# Termination grace period for a full Kubernetes emptyDIr?

Tags: kubernetes

As far as I can tell, if a Kubernetes pod fills an emptyDir volume that has a sizeLimit, the pod is immediately evicted, without following normal termination procedure.   (terminationGracePeriodSeconds, et cetera)

Is there a way to set a soft eviction threshold for an emptyDir volumes so that it does follow normal termination procedures?

If not, does anybody have a good suggestion on how to build an appropriate livenessProbe?   `df` shows disk free for the underlying disk, not the emptyDir, and `du` can be quite expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your soft eviction thresholds for the kubelet

There are 3 parameters `eviction-soft`, `eviction-soft-grace-period`, and `eviction-max-pod-grace-period`

More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#soft-eviction-thresholds)

Comment: eviction-soft and eviction-soft-grace-period aren't relevant, since they configure the events on the *node* that trigger eviction.

Comment: eviction-max-pod-grace-period is relevant; but it's a global parameter that normally you want to keep at 0: if a node runs out of disk or memory you need to terminate pods immediately.   A node running out of disk is a very different condition than a pod running out of disk.

Comment: afaik evictions happen at the node level. (pods get evicted) where are the docs about eviction from the pod itself? thx.

Comment: That's a really good question!   I would love to know where they are, if there are any.   All I have to go on is the behaviour I observe: I set up a pod with an emptyDir volume, fill up that emptyDir and notice the pod getting evicted.